# iOS6, StoryBoards: UISearchDisplayController returns wrong custom UICell height

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I use custom cells in storyboard with height set to 57.

[image]

While searching in tableView,`UISearchDisplayController` returns my custom cell but the height is wrong.

[image]

Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellReuseIdentifier = @"Cell";
CommemorativeItemCell *cell =[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellReuseIdentifier];

KmCell *kmCell=nil;

if(tableView==self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
{
   kmCell=[self.filteredResult objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
}
else
{
    kmCell=[self.arr objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
}

// bla bla filling up and drawing labels...

return cell;
}
```

How to make the cells UISearchDisplayController returns to be of the same height? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the height of the search results cells in viewDidLoad with

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.rowHeight = 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method this may help you!

You can return number as you want instead of 110.
For example i am using 110.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 110;
}
```